# Removed HDD - ubuntu still looks for it at boot

Tags: 11.10, boot, hard-drive

I removed a drive (SDC1) from my Ubuntu PC and would like to find out how to stop the OS trying to access it during boot up.

Comment: To answer this question more precisely, you should provide an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the entry for it in `/etc/fstab`.